# Catch an pre-defined int exception

Tags: c++

I have defined a simple int error code:

```
#define my_error 20
```

Somewhere in my code I throw this error:

```
throw my_error;
```

Now I want to try and catch this exception thrown:

```
try
{
    ...
    ...
}
catch (my_error)
{
    cout << "Error: my error";
}
```

Unfortunately the compiler doesn't approve this:

- syntax error : 'constant'
- catch handlers must specify one type
- 'try' block starting on line '34' has no catch handlers

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Quick fix: `#define my_error int(20)` ; followed by `catch(int)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`20` is not a type, so you can't catch it. What you can do is filter the values in the `catch` block:

```
catch (int exception)
{
    if ( exception == 20 )
        cout << "Error: my error";
}
```

An even better approach would be to define your own exception:

```
class MyException : public std::exception
{
}

//...

try
{
   throw MyException();
}
catch(MyException& ex)
{
}
```

Comment: got it, thanks. i chose the simpler approach because i just wanted to do something quick and dirty with min overhead

Answer (score 4):

If you use C++11, you can use `decltype(my_error)`, just in case you ever change the type of `my_error`.

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (const decltype(my_error)& e) {
  // ...
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/asKR9).