# C++ catch enum value as exception

Tags: c++, exception, shared-libraries

I am trying to use an *external* `C++` library which have defined its exceptions as:

```
enum MY_ERRORS {
    ERR_NONE = 0,
    ERR_T1,
    ERR_T2,
};
```

Then in the code exceptions are thrown like this:

```
if(...) {
    throw ERR_T1;
```

Being new to programming in C++, I would do something like:

```
try {
    call_to_external_library();
} catch(??? err) {
    printf("An error occurred: %s\n", err);
} catch(...) {
    printf("An unexpected exception occurred.\n");
}
```

**How do I determine what was thrown?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch an pre-defined int exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615135/catch-an-pre-defined-int-exception)

Comment: `err` should be `MY_ERRORS` or `const MY_ERRORS&` or something like this (doesn't matter much for `enum`s). In the `catch( ... )` you cannot get the type of the caught exception

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to write your code to handle the type of enumeration in the catch block:

```
try {
    call_to_external_library();
} catch(MY_ERRORS err) {      // <------------------------ HERE
    printf("An error occurred: %s\n", err);
} catch(...) {
    printf("An unexpected exception occurred.\n");
}
```

Comment: You might consider wrapping the enum in a type that derives from `std::exception` so that it can be caught like a normal exception.  Not necessary, but it can be nice to have a more uniform way to catch things.

Answer (score 5):

You must catch the type `MY_ERRORS` and then compare against the possible values

```c++
try {
    call_to_external_library();
} catch(MY_ERRORS err) {
    printf("An error occurred: %s\n", err);
} catch(...) {
    printf("An unexpected exception occurred.\n");
}
```