# Error Handling using enum

Tags: c++, exception

In my project, I'm setting up an error handling system, but before I put in the code, I setup a test project to get a foundation to build off of. I have everything I need, except for one thing, which is the error.ToMessage() function. Problem is, I don't know how to set up the function in the way I have built it and can't find examples.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostrea>

enum class ErrorCode {
    StreamError,
    FileError,
    CloseError
};

int main() {

    try {
        throw ErrorCode::StreamError
    } catch (ErrorCode err) {
        //std::cout << err.ToMessage() << std::endl; //This is how I would like to output the error.
        switch (err) {
        case ErrorCode::StreamError:
            std::cout << "Stream Error"; //This is how it's currently done.
        //...
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this, if it's possible?

Comment: Create class ErrorCode (should inherit from std::exception), not enum.

Comment: See [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/) and you can see under standard exceptions an example of what Ed S has stated in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an addition to all the other answers, which recommend creating your own exception class (and inheriting `std::exception`, which is a commonly recommended practice).

If you don't want to go that way, consider making a free-standing (global) function:

```
enum class ErrorCode {
    StreamError,
    FileError,
    CloseError
};

std::string ToMessage(ErrorCode e)
{
    switch (err) {
    case ErrorCode::StreamError: return "Stream Error";
    case ...
    default: ...
    }
}
```

You can use any implementation inside the function: a `switch` statement, a LUT or a `std::map`.

Comment: This is not a good idea because code that's based on standard exceptions won't know anything about `ToMessage`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need more than an `enum` to accomplish this. What you can do is to create your own exception type which inherits from `std::exception`.  This class would have an `ErrorCode` member (for your enum) as well as a `what()` method, which returns a `string` (already there for you in `std::exception`).

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a class that handle the exception and put all the switch case in this class that will generate the string for all exception catched

Answer (score 1):

The standard library's solution is the [`std::system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) class, which is derived from `std::runtime_error`, which is derived from the top level exception class `std::exception`.

`std::exception::what` can be used to obtain an exception message.

If you find the standard class to be unsuitable for your purposes, then derive a class from `std::runtime_error` or from `std::system_error`.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate as:
[C++ catch enum value as exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951134/c-catch-enum-value-as-exception)

You can put enum in a derived classs from std::exception and then handle the exception in there

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>

#define enum_name(a) #a

enum test_enum
{
    LOL,
    OKAY,
    NOPE,
    YOU,
    ARE,
    SEXY
};

int main() 
{
    auto test = test_enum::SEXY;
    std::cout << enum_name(test);
    return 0;
}
```